# React native production Android app crash - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError couldn't find DSO to load

Tags: android, react-native

Im having this phantom error that i cannot replicate on my development machine and my device/simulator.

Its happening in production and is being logged in firebase crashlytics.

Firebase logged it happening on OnePlus8Pro and Nexus 5X. I have ran Nexus 5X simulator on Android studio but crash does not happened.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-main flags = 1] 
SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-0 flags = 
1] SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-1 
flags = 1] SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = 
/data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-2 flags = 1] SoSource 4: 
com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-3 flags = 1] SoSource 
5: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-4 flags = 1] 
SoSource 6: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-5 flags = 
1] SoSource 7: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-6 
flags = 1] SoSource 8: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = 
/data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-7 flags = 1] SoSource 9: 
com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-8 flags = 1] SoSource 
10: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-9 flags = 1] 
SoSource 11: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-10 flags = 
1] SoSource 12: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-11 
flags = 1] SoSource 13: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = 
/data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-12 flags = 1] SoSource 14: 
com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-13 flags = 1] 
SoSource 15: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-14 flags 
= 1] SoSource 16: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-15 
flags = 1] SoSource 17: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = 
/data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-16 flags = 1] SoSource 18: 
com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-17 flags = 1] 
SoSource 19: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-18 flags 
= 1] SoSource 20: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.hzppapp/lib-19 
flags = 1] SoSource <truncated: 6863 chars>
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "2.3.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 15 Pro'",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.6",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.11.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^10.3.2",
    "react-native-in-app-review": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.17.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.2",
    "recoil": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/base-64": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-native-base64": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```